# Alternative to Gmail Postfix relay

Tags: postfix, gmail

I have been using Gmail as a Postfix relay for years. Works perfectly. But it [seems that on May 30th 2022 this will be disabled by Google](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6010255). They will not allow us to use "less secure apps" that rely only on username/password authentication.

So I need a solution. I need either a way to continue using Gmail as a Postfix relay or I need an alternative to Gmail (free and that doesn't block my emails due to spam policies).

Sending email directly from the server is not an option. I need a Postfix relay.

Comment: related: [Postfix using OAuth2 authentication for relay host](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/584125/postfix-using-oauth2-authentication-for-relay-host)

Comment: The cited Google support page includes this: _using only your username and password_. That's important; there are other ways to log in, in particular using an app-specific password (see https://serverfault.com/a/1101310/536539).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is an option called "App passwords" in the security tab of the Google account dashboard. It is only available after you enable 2-step verification. This option provides a single use password that can be used in Postfix relay. It seems that this option will remain available after May 30th 2022.

Comment: I don't understand why the app password has an "app name" with it, but in the Postfix config file the name never appears.  How do I tell Postfix which app name to use? (If I have multiple app passwords in my Google account?)